# Как удалить репозиторий из bitbucket.org? Название репозитория по ошибке задан на кириллице

Tags: bitbucket

Создал по ошибке репозиторий, название репозитория по ошибке задал на кириллице.
Понимаю, что он не должен был создавать заведомо неправильный репозиторий. А так же понимаю, что можно обратиться в службу поддержки. Написал, но пока молчать.
Кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 6):

```
https://bitbucket.org/[имя пользователя]/[имя репозитория]/delete
```

Или зайти: в репозиторий -> Настройки -> Удалить репозиторий

Можно попробовать переименовать его:

```
https://bitbucket.org/[имя пользователя]/[имя репозитория]/admin
```

Comment: Не работает. Пробовал и так и сяк (

Comment: @Sergey: каким образом не работает? Сообщение об ошибке есть? У меня все работает точно по этой инструкции, с кириллическим именем.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Http ошибки нет, просто говорить, что страница отсутствует.

Answer (score 4):

**Лучше один раз увидеть, чем сто раз услышать ;)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все работает как нарисовано

Answer (score 3):

В bitbucket, когда заходишь в репозиторий, слева внизу есть пункт меню настройки. Заходишь в настройки и в самом низу есть кнопочка удалить репозиторий. Жмешь и репозиторий удаляеться

Comment: Когда кирилица, даже страница не открывалась. С того времени не проверял.

Answer (score 0):

Пишу ответ на свой вопрос спустя n лет.
Никак. Нужно писать в техподдержку, а они уже удалят.

Comment: Рядом инструкция по тому, как удалить самостоятельно. Что-то не получилось?

Comment: Они судя по всему исправили баг.